# php DOM XML generate XML with line break after reopening

Tags: php, xml, dom, object

So I have this code

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$rootElt = $domDoc->createElement('CONFIG');
$rootNode = $domDoc->appendChild($rootElt);

$subElt = $domDoc->createElement('APP-ID');
$subNode = $rootNode->appendChild($subElt);

$textNode = $domDoc->createTextNode('166533e56');
$subNode->appendChild($textNode);

$domDoc->save('config.xml');
```

That generated

```
<CONFIG><APP-ID>166533e56</APP-ID></CONFIG>
```

This is without line breaks. 
When I add

```
$domDoc->formatOutput = true;
```

just before code's last line

```
$domDoc->save('config.xml');
```

The output is now fine:

```
<CONFIG>
  <APP-ID>166533e56</APP-ID>
</CONFIG>
```

However, when I in another php try to open the xml and write something in it, it is appended there unformatted no matter what I try.

In another php code I do:

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$domDoc->load('config.xml');

$rootNode = $domDoc->documentElement;
$config_root = $rootNode->getElementsByTagName("CONFIG");

$rootElt = $domDoc->createElement('USER-ID');
$subNode = $rootNode->appendChild($rootElt);

$textNode = $domDoc->createTextNode('333265332f');
$subNode->appendChild($textNode);

$rootElt = $domDoc->createElement('USER-NAME');
$sub2Node = $rootNode->appendChild($rootElt);

$textNode = $domDoc->createTextNode('John');
$sub2Node->appendChild($textNode);

$domDoc->formatOutput = true;
$domDoc->save('config.xml');
```

that results in

```
<CONFIG>
  <APP-ID>166533e56</APP-ID>
<USER-ID>333265332f</USER-ID><USER-NAME>John</USER-NAME></CONFIG>
```

which is totally wrong. It should be

```
<CONFIG>
  <APP-ID>166533e56</APP-ID>
  <USER-ID>333265332f</USER-ID>
  <USER-NAME>John</USER-NAME>
</CONFIG>
```

Why Line Breaks havent been added? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `$domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` **before** you load the file:

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;// <-- this line
$domDoc->loadXML(<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CONFIG>
  <APP-ID>166533e56</APP-ID>
</CONFIG>
XML
);

$rootNode = $domDoc->documentElement;
$config_root = $rootNode->getElementsByTagName("CONFIG");

$rootElt = $domDoc->createElement('USER-ID');
$subNode = $rootNode->appendChild($rootElt);

$textNode = $domDoc->createTextNode('333265332f');
$subNode->appendChild($textNode);

$rootElt = $domDoc->createElement('USER-NAME');
$sub2Node = $rootNode->appendChild($rootElt);

$textNode = $domDoc->createTextNode('John');
$sub2Node->appendChild($textNode);

$domDoc->formatOutput = true;
//$domDoc->save('config.xml');    
echo $domDoc->saveXML();
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/oZrBs)

Comment: #{$! it works! man thank you 10x I've been figuring this out for 2 hours already!